# How to merge two tables with having a common attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named "User" and "EndpointSubnet".

- USER table has 3 attributes namely 'UserKey', 'URI' and 'NextUpdateTS'
- ENDPOINTSUBNET table has 2 attributes namely 'SubnetIP' and 'NextUpdateTS'.

`NextUpdateTS` attribute is common to both tables.

URI is the LoginId of the employees and SubnetIP is their IP address.

What I need to do is to merge both the table using common attribute i.e.NextUpdateTS.

The table must look like that:

```
UserKey | URI | SubnetIP | NextUpdateTS
```

I have written a query. It is giving output but in this query 'SubnetIP' is not displaying:

```
SELECT [URI],[UserKey],[NextUpdateTS] 
FROM [User] 
WHERE [NextUpdateTS] 
  IN(
   SELECT [NextUpdateTS] 
   FROM [User] 
   INTERSECT 
   (SELECT [NextUpdateTS] FROM [EndpointSubnet]))
```

Please tell me where to put SubnetIP in this query

Comment: You should really tell us which SQL dialect you are using. I believe you did, but DarkGray removed it?

Comment: From what I can see it only said c#-4.0, which implies sql server. @user1280381 Welcome to stackoverflow. With sql questions, always include your db type and version. As there are many syntax differences between db engines. So knowing which one you are using helps us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a simple join?

```
SELECT [URI],[UserKey],[NextUpdateTS],[SubnetIP]
FROM [User]
JOIN [EndpointSubnet] ON [EndpointSubnet].[NextUpdateTS] = [User].[NextUpdateTS]
```

Answer (score 0):

What DBMS are you using? In MySQL it would be a simple `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.URI, u.UserKey, es.SubnetIP, u.NextUpdateTS
FROM User u
INNER JOIN EndpointSubnet es ON u.NextUpdateTS = es.NextUpdateTS
```

Other DBMS may differ slightly but should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need JOIN.

```
SELECT UserKey, URI, SubnetIP, User.NextUpdateTS
FROM User
JOIN EndpointSubnet
ON User.NextUpdateTS = EndpointSubnet.NextUpdateTS
```

To avoid the "ambiguous column" error, put in `User.` in front of `NextUpdateTS`. There are two columns with the name in those two tables; the system always needs to know which column to display, compare etc.

Comment: It is not working...an error occurs "ambiguous column name NextUpdateTS"....I am Using Visual studio 2008 with C#...and I am working on Web Application....If there is some different syntax in c#?

Comment: Updated the answer. I should have paid attention in the first place :)